# How in the angular output information obtained through the "get"?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, angular-promise, angular-http

How do I write the received data in `tmp`? Through `return`, the`promise` object is returned from the function, and in the function `tmp` it is not visible

```
tmp: string;

constructor(private http: Http) {
  this.tmp = "load";
  this.GetUsers();
}

ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(console.log("Hello"), 2000);
}
GetUsers() {
   this.http.get('http://localhost:1337/api/users')
    .toPromise()
     .then(function(response) {
       this.tmp = "success"
     })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Also, `setTimeout` does not work. That is, it only works once and all.

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
  this.tmp = "load";
  this.GetUsers();
}

ngOnInit() {
}
GetUsers() {
  setTimeout(console.log("Hello"), 2000);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'record'?

Comment: @Flaugzig write

Comment: setTimeout is executing once by design. See also [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)  page.

Comment: I still dont understand your question. Do you want to extract the data from the response?

Comment: @Flaugzig I want to know how to get the data and write it to the correct variable. I sorry if asked an unclear question

Comment: @Nikolay Can you please tell me where you are adding setTimeout()

Comment: @Nikolay It is nothing about `setTimeout()`. It is about where you are using it. If you will let me for what purpose you want use `setTimeout()` then i might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

Add import for Response from `@angular/http`

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:1337/api/users') 
      .toPromise() 
      .then((response:Response)=> { this.tmp = response.json() }) 
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

The `ngOnInit()` life cycle hook in which you have written the `setTimeout()` will execute only once after constructor. If the written code is in component then it will execute every time component object is created but if it in service then it will execute once when you provide the service since service object is singleton object

Comment: Thanks for `this.http.get`. setTimeout not working in another function too.

Comment: Can you please tell me where you are adding setTimeout()

Comment: It is nothing about `setTimeout()`. It is about where you are using it. If you will let me for what purpose you want use `setTimeout()` then i might be able to help you.

Comment: function `GetUsers`

Comment: Sorry but i am not able to get you. Can you please modify your code how you are trying it.

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149480/discussion-between-prathmesh-dali-and-nikolay).